# Jquery para de funcionar após execução do comando load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou usando o comando

```
$("#teste").load(location.href+" #teste>*",{id : idd});
```

O comando atualiza os dados  `div` grupo e envia um `parâmetro` para o mesmo.
O `div`, tem class, comandos `jquery` que interage com o usuário. Ao carregar a tela depois da execução do comando, e se for novamente executar o comando acima, o  `jquery`, estilos, etc não funcionam mais.

Exemplo:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="teste">
    <input type="button" value="Clique aqui para Apagar o Resgistro 1" class="btn">Registro 1
    <input type="button" value="Clique aqui para Apagar o Resgistro 10" class="btn">
    <input type="button" value="Clique aqui para Apagar o Resgistro 20" class="btn">
</div>
```

Ao clicar em algum botão executa o código abaixo.

**JS:**

```
function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "Registros.php",
        data: {ta : tipoacao, dados : dados},
        type: "POST"
      })
      .done(function(data) {           
        $("#teste").load(location.href+" #teste>*",{id : ta});

      })
      .error(function(data) {        
      });
    });

Resultado (clicou para apagar o Registro 1)
<div id="teste">    
    <input type="button" value="Clique aqui para Apagar o Resgistro 10" class="btn">
    <input type="button" value="Clique aqui para Apagar o Resgistro 20" class="btn">
</div>
```

Mostra sem o registro 1, mas ao clicar novamente em algum botão não chama mais o ajax, não tem mais estilo no botão.

Comment: Atualiza uma div com o load ? Pra mim load carrega um arquivo externo, tente melhorar sua pergunta explicando o que você esta tentando fazer e poste  um código que possa reproduzir o problema

Comment: exemplo postado @Highlander

Comment: @Highlander isso mesmo. Carrega um arquivo externo. Neste caso eu uso para recarregar parte do mesmo arquivo em questão. Ao recarregar essa parte do arquivo, conforme relatado, os botões não funcionam mais, js não funciona mais .

Answer (score 1):

Isso porque você refez o DOM, e os eventos não foram atrelados aos elementos após o novo DOM ser criado.
Utilize **event delegate**

```
$('body').on('click', '.sua-class', function() {
   //...
});
```

Comment: Obrigado. no caso não estou usando classe e sim id do botão, então so referenciar o id né.

Comment: yep.. mesma coisa.